# What does the expression "sour mouth" mean? 口を酸っぱくして

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

> オレが口を酸っぱくして教えたよね？

To my understanding, it means "Did I teach you to do it with a sour mouth?" or actually, "Didn't I teach you with a sour mouth?", but I'm not sure what sour mouth means.

Comment: Given your translation attempt, is 終えた a typo for 教えた? At any rate, entering "口を酸っぱくして" in your favorite search engine will quickly lead you to [answers like this one](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8F%A3%E3%82%92%E9%85%B8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B1%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86).

Answer (score 1):

口を酸っぱくして教える means "tell [somebody something] over and over again [without any effect]".  教える here is "tell" rather than "teach". A corresponding English idiom would be "I've told you till I'm blue in the face!" I imagine the underlying meaning is "I've said this so many times I've got a sour taste in my mouth".